# Does SandBoxie have a virus?

Tags: virus, antivirus

When I try to download SandBoxie in the 64-bit version, at this link: [SandBoxie](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/downloads/eula.aspx?downloadKey=f42ecfd5-66c4-4a3e-b209-6a8c6aa7abaf&entitlementId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) and I analyze it with [VirusTotal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirusTotal), it tells me that it's safe, but when I analyze some relative files, called:

- 066cca997f12a387f6ea0459e7a2f9a8cf7e842236fa624ef658b5a85571a860
- sandbox.exe
- SandboxieInstall
- SandboxieInstall-533-3.exe
- s.exe
- 57241f48b77aebbb78d6a99b90895d7b.virus
- WindowsApplication4.exe

Among others... It detects between 44 and 63 viruses in each one, and that is a very big amount of virus... So, does SandBoxie have viruses? Or rather, does the SandBoxie installer have a virus?

Comment: I believe it's open source now, so feel free to audit and compile it yourself.

Comment: @user But they use very strange libraries and I am not very expert in C ++; if I don't know those libraries much less will I know how to test that code ... They use things that are too strange for me.